# Vuetify External pagination in Data table with CRUD Actions

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to add pagination like [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables#external-pagination) in Data Table with [CRUD Actions](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables#crud-actions), but i have nothing after table.
How can i fix this?

[Here is the image what i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cca5m.png)

```
<template>
    <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="desserts"
    :page.sync="page"
    :items-per-page="itemsPerPage"
    hide-default-footer
    class="elevation-1"
    @page-count="pageCount = $event"
  >
    <template v-slot:item.action="{ item }">
      <v-icon
        small
        class="mr-2"
        @click="editItem(item)"
      >
        mdi-pencil
      </v-icon>
      <v-icon
        small
        @click="deleteItem(item)"
      >
        mdi-delete
      </v-icon>
    </template>
    <div class="text-center pt-2">
      <v-pagination v-model="page" :length="pageCount"></v-pagination>
    </div>
  </v-data-table>
</template>
```

Comment: I believe you are using the wrong property name - should not it be `:pagination.sync` ? I do not think there is a property `items-per-page` - it should be part of the object that you will provide for `:pagination.sync`

Comment: @IVOGELOV i tried to change it and now i have all items from my list of data, so the items-per-page work, because i count it as 3 and as u can see in picture i have 3 items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the answer how to do it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WzeBETaey5s)
My mistake was that i didn't provide the property Pages as in the documentation